# How to access the syntax tree generated in another file in C# source generator?

Tags: c#, sourcegenerators

I am writing a source generator in C#. First I get the class I need which I find by using an attribute. Then I need to find a class which is in another file. But I can't seem to find it.

My code is too long to put here but this is the way I am trying to do it :

```cs
services = classDeclarationSyntax.SyntaxTree.GetRoot().DescendantNodes()
                    .OfType<ClassDeclarationSyntax>()
                    .Where(n => n.Identifier.Text.Contains("Service")).ToList();
```

Obviously I am looking for classes that end with `Service`. If I put the classes in the same file it works fine but separating them breaks it. I think that it creates separate syntax trees for each file so getting the root node does not work.

Any idea on how to solve this?

Comment: In [Introducing C# Source Generators](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-c-source-generators/) I see the line `context.Compilation.SyntaxTrees`. Wouldn't that allow you to search for other syntax trees?

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes yeah! thank you it worked (you can post an answer to get upvote from me). But we should NEVER do this kind of lookups in a source generators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Compilation.SyntaxTrees Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.compilation.syntaxtrees) from the [Compilation Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.compilation) (the compilation context).